# Tranfer data from local variable to global in javascript

Tags: javascript, ajax, json, variables

I have some problem with transfer of variable outside the function.
It's seems to be very simple but I have some problem with it.

```
var myJson;
var url = "https://openbook.etoro.com/api/Markets/Symbol/?name=" + symbol;
var xhr = (window.XMLHttpRequest ? new XMLHttpRequest() : new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP"));
xhr.onreadystatechange = XHRhandler;
xhr.open("GET", "proxy.php?url=" + url, true);
xhr.send(null);

function XHRhandler() {

    if (xhr.readyState == 4) {

        var json;
        if (JSON && JSON.parse) {
            json = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
        } else {
            eval("var json = " + xhr.responseText);
        }
        console.log(json);
        myJson= json;
        xhr = null;
    }

}
console.log(myJson);
```

What I need is to pass the data from local variable json to global myJson;
But when i do console.log(myJson) i get undefined.
What is the problem?

Thank you

Comment: It is undefined since `console.log(myJson);` executes immediately without waiting for xhr to complete. XHRhandler will be called only when the data arrived from the server.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to return the response from an AJAX call?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-ajax-call)

Comment: You can also try `promise` and set variable in its callback.

Answer (score 0):

Try moving the statement `console.log(myJson);` inside your if condition or alternately initialize your variable with some value. It seems your statement is getting called before it is getting populated with any value.

Answer (score 0):

The XMLHttpRequest is async so it is not done yet when you try to write the myJson variable to console. Wrap it in a function and call that function after the XMLHttpRequest is completed instead.

```js
var myJson;
var url = "https://openbook.etoro.com/api/Markets/Symbol/?name=" + symbol;
var xhr = (window.XMLHttpRequest ? new XMLHttpRequest() : new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP"));
xhr.onreadystatechange = XHRhandler;
xhr.open("GET", "proxy.php?url=" + url, true);
xhr.send(null);

function XHRhandler() {

    if (xhr.readyState == 4) {

        var json;
        if (JSON && JSON.parse) {
            json = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
        } else {
            eval("var json = " + xhr.responseText);
        }
        console.log(json);
        myJson= json;
        xhr = null;
        writeToConsole();
    }

}

function writeToConsole() {
    console.log(myJson);
}
```